# Windows phone 8.0 sdk visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, failed-installation

I am stuck with this now, I had windows phone sdk installed on vs 2012 but suddenly, creating a project in it starts to give me object reference not set to an instance error! could not create project.

I uninstalled sdk ,uninstalled vs2012, installed again and now when i try to install phone sdk 8.0 i get this error saying
 Microsoft visual studio express 2012 for windows phone cannot find requested object.
 Windows phone 8.0 Emulator images Cannot find the requested object.

I am having heads gone moments now! please help..

I have windows 8 pro 64 bit and do have hyper v enabled and checked.[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same happened to me.
it occurs because of corrupted .iso file.
so either download a new one or install using online installation, i'm afraid but this is the only possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to either update or uninstall NuGet. This worked for me: **UNINSTALLED** NuGet (as updates to it did not work)